# BroadcastReceiver not receiving broadcast from IntentService in Android

Tags: android, intentservice, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm sending a progress value like `int progress = 10` via `Broadcast` from `IntentService` to display the progress of uploading file.

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.setAction(SendList.mReceiver.TEST);
    try {
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("Count",mArraylist.size());
        [...uploading data...]
        for (int i = 0; i < mArrayList.size(); i++) {
            broadcastIntent.putExtra("progress", i);
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
            //...
        }
}
```

So in my `Activity` I register the receiver but it is never called.

```
public class SendList extends Activity {
TextView textResult;
ProgressBar progressbar;
boolean mIsReceiverRegistered = false;
BroadcastReceiver receiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.sendlist);
    textResult= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.maxFragments);
    progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(!mIsReceiverRegistered) {
        if (receiver == null)
            receiver = new FragmentReceiver();
        registerReceiver(receiver,new IntentFilter(mReceiver.TEST));
        mIsReceiverRegistered = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(mIsReceiverRegistered) {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        receiver = null;
        mIsReceiverRegistered = false;
    }
}

private void updateUI (Intent intent) {
    progressbar.setProgress(intent.getIntExtra("progress", 0));
}

public class mReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String TEST = "upload";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int count = intent.getIntExtra("Count",0);
        progressbar.setMax(count);
        textResult.setText(count);

        updateUI(intent);
    }
}
```

Where could be the problem? What am I doing wrong? Have I forgotten something?

Thanks for any help!

Kind Regards!

Comment: can you please register your broadcast in onStart and un-register it onStop

Comment: is there a big difference? I see some ppl using onResume and others onStart... So what is now the right one?

Comment: Do you have the receiver in your Manifest?

Comment: I'm registering the receiver in `OnResume()`

Comment: You are missing to start your intent service o_O !!? @raymondis

Comment: No, when I'm debugging it is working fine.

Comment: where you exactly stuck ? your receiver is not being called ?

Comment: That's correct. My receiver in `SendList` is not beeing called

Comment: Just try to get Count value rather than progress at the same time and let me know .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to register you receiver as below -

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(SendList.mReceiver.TEST);
registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

while broadcasting you are sending action as below

```
broadcastIntent.setAction(SendList.mReceiver.TEST);
```

and when you register it is different.

```
registerReceiver(receiver,new IntentFilter(FragmentReceiver.TEST));
```

Your action should be same while sending and receiving.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: What is the value of both, SendList.mReceiver.TEST and FragmentReceiver.TEST?

Comment: it is both the same. It is `public static final String TEST = "upload";`